# Как обновить нужную ячейку в SQlite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telegram-bot

Доброго времени суток.

Проблема заключается в следующем - пытаюсь обновить 4-ю колонку в БД, но всегда обновляется почему-то только вторая

```
def update_subscription(self, user_id, money):
    """Обновляем статус подписки пользователя"""
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `money` WHERE `user_id` = ?""", (money, user_id))


 if  1 == 1:
     bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'успех!', reply_markup=markup)
     db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, 150)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновляю колонку money, но почему-то обновляется только колонка first_name, как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли сохранить действие после `self.cursor.execute` напишите `db.commit()`

Comment: Поставил, но всё так же не в ту колонку записывает, у меня нет проблемы с тем чтобы запись сохранилась, она записывается и сохраняется, только не в ту колонку.

Comment: self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE subscriptions SET money WHERE user_id = ?""", (money, user_id,))
Скопируйте и вставьте место своего

Comment: Нууу как? Вам помогло?

Comment: скопировал вставил, всё равно записало 150 в fist_name, вместо money

Comment: Скиньте пожайлуста весь код связан с етой частью

Comment: def update_subscription(self, user_id, money):
        """Обновляем статус подписки пользователя"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE subscriptions SET money WHERE user_id = ?""", (money, user_id,))

if  1 == 1:
db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, 150)

Comment: Так возможно вам ето поможет `self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE subscriptions SET money=? WHERE user_id = ?""", (money, user_id,))`

Comment: всё равно обновляет не ту ячейку, может быть проблема в этой строчке - db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, 150) ?

Comment: Я даже и не знаю

Comment: А попробуйте поменять код в функции на етот: `self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE subscriptions SET money WHERE user_id = ?""", (money, user_id))     
db.commit()`
И удалите бд

Comment: не помогло, так же в first_name пишет

Comment: Скиньте скрин кода полностю

Comment: Так что вам помогло?